# Jasper Reports: multi line text field

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm generating a pdf report with Jasper Reports 3.1.2. I have a multi line text field that contains several lines: this field is split over 2 consecutive pages.
The problem is that on AiX and Linux systems the last line in the first page is always missing (on Windows systems everything is fine). I've tried modifying margins, sizes and fonts but nothing happens: the last line of the first page is always missing

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What font are you using? Problems like this are usually† caused by fonts not being available. Use [font extensions](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/jaspersoft-v3-7-font-extensions/) to ensure that you know what font is being used, and then it should render well everywhere.

Also make sure to set this in jasperreports.properties:
net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font=false

That's great for testing since it catches missing fonts immediately.

†By "usually" I mean "so often that it's indistinguishable from always". But of course it's theoretically possible that there is some other source in this case.

Comment: Agree with this theory. The fact it works on Win environment supports it strongly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried to set jasperreports.properties as you suggested, but nothing changes. No exception is thrown and the pdf is produced correctly, with Courier font, as I expected. Trying to set a font name that does not exist, the exception occurs as expected

Comment: Your pesky actual results are confounding my beautiful theory. I don't know fonts well enough to know if it's likely (or even possible) that Courier has different metrics on Windows vs Linux. That would explain it. Or there could be some sort of issue with net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer or net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JdkGlyphFixTextMeasurer. Try swapping to whichever of those you aren't currently using in jasperreports.properties.

Comment: Even using JdkGlyphFixTextMeasurer I've the same problem. I solved the problem converting the large text in a list of string (one per line) and then adding a subreport that displays each line.  No way to understand this strange behavior